# simultaneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following simultaneous differential equation that i cannot solve.

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 2x - y$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -x+2y+2e^t$$

if i differentiate the first term with respect to $t$ i can put the second term into the first which looks like.

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = 2\frac{dx}{dt}-x+2y+2e^2$$
which can be rearranged to
$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}- 2\frac{dx}{dt}+x = 2y+2e^2$$
The issue is the leaves a $y$ on the rhs which shouldnt be there. Its the same thing if i differentiate the second equation and insert the first into it.

I cant see a way to get rid of the $y$ to complete the problem, is there something i am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You should rather do the following:

$$y=2x-\frac{dx}{dt}$$ plug this into the second equation.

$$2\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-x+2(2x-\frac{dx}{dt})+2e^t$$

Comment: thanks, feel stupid for not seeing such simple thing

Comment: No problem :). Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach consists in adding the two ODEs :
$$\frac{dy+dx}{dt}=x+y+2e^t = \frac{du}{dt}=u+2e^t\quad\text{where}\quad u=y+x$$
This first order linear ODE is easy to solve :
$$u=2t\:e^t+c_1e^t \quad\to\quad y=-x+2t\:e^t+c_1e^t$$
Puting it into the first ODE : $\quad \frac{dx}{dt}=3x-2t\:e^t-c_1e^t$

Solving this first order linear ODE leads to $x(t)$, then $y(t)$ with the above relationship.